# Scaffolding view with "Create" template, getting error when running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This has been answered multiple times, but I have tried to follow the answers and still no success.

Error message:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MovieID'
```

My model:

```
public class Show
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public int TheaterID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public string BookingLink { get; set; }
        public string StartTimeAsString { get; set; }

        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public Theater Theater { get; set; }
    }
```

Where it crashes:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("MovieID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("TheaterID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TheaterID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

The view is autogenerated through the "Create" template.
Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: You're returning a list of `SelectListItem`s as your model.  This isn't the same as returning `IEnumerable<Show>`.  It is `Show` that has the MovieID property, not `SelectListItem`...

Comment: I dont get it. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` anywhere within your `DropDownFor` helpers [as it expects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29).

Your `Show` class should contain a property for both select lists, so that the drop down knows what items to display:

```
public class Show
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public int TheaterID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string BookingLink { get; set; }
    public string StartTimeAsString { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public Theater Theater { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Theatres { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Moview { get; set; }
}
```

You should populate these properties in your Model before you pass them to your view and then pass them into your `Html.DropDownListFor` helpers:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MovieID, model.Movies, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MovieID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TheaterID, model.Theatres, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TheaterID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: No, my model is like this
`@model CinemaWeb.Models.Show`
:(

Comment: I don't have "SelectListItem" anywere in my solution

Comment: Glad to have helped :)